# how to use if statements on a pair of muons

Tags: c++

I am using c++ to run a script below. I have three number of muons having values `0,1,2`. I am making pair of these and then fill histograms. But the if statements are not working properly. when i use `mu3==0`, it means the `h1` fills only mu1 and `mu2` pair with values 1,2. But all the histograms are filling same.

```
j=0;
for(unsigned int mu1=0; mu1 <nMu; ++mu1){
  jj=0;
  for(unsigned int mu2=0; mu2 <nMu; ++mu2) {
    if( (mu2 > mu1) &&  (VetoMu_charge[mu1]*VetoMu_charge[mu2]) < 0. ) {
      tmp1.SetPxPyPzE(VetoMu_px[mu1], VetoMu_py[mu1], VetoMu_pz[mu1],       VetoMu_en[mu1]);
      tmp2.SetPxPyPzE(VetoMu_px[mu2], VetoMu_py[mu2], VetoMu_pz[mu2],  VetoMu_en[mu2]);
      for(unsigned int mu3=0; mu3 < nMu; mu3++)  {
        if(mu3==0){
          h1->Fill((tmp1 + tmp2).M());
        }
        else if(mu3==1){
          h2->Fill((tmp1 + tmp2).M());
        }
        else if(mu3==2){
          h3->Fill((tmp1 + tmp2).M());
        }
      }
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Muons? Like [mu-mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon)? C++ does not have a concept of elementary particles. What do you mean by "But all the histograms are filling same"? Have you checked the value of `mu3` in every case?

Comment: muons is just a number. I am assigning numbers like 1,2 and 3. They are not like an elementary particles, treat them as a numbers.

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: why do they even should be different? you pass sum of `tmp1` and `tmp2` to every `Fill` and it's is not use mu3 at all. Looks like h1-h3 objects has the same data inside. P.S. use `switch .. case` instead of `if .. else`